# how does the browser tell the difference between user click and programmatic click?

Tags: jquery, browser, click

If I initiate a click with jquery which does `window.open()`, it is blocked by pop up blocker, If I do the click manually the window is not blocked. How does the browser differ between the two?

Comment: Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/twMSG/1/) to demonstrate. It'll try to popup on page load but get blocked. Calling the `click` event programmatically causes it to get blocked but if you call it within another click event it goes through.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Firefox implementation of this is discussed at length on [this bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=197919), and [this other bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=126224) has some further interesting background, including what lengths sites will go through in order to foist an unwanted popup window on unsuspecting users (in this case: calling `window.open()` from within an image `load` event).  If you search around Bugzilla you'll find that the Mozilla people took a number of years to get this all working correctly, for example [here's a bug from 2001](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=92955).

The way it works currently is this:  When Firefox receives a click event from the operating system, for a certain amount of time `window.open()` is enabled in JavaScript (look for `dom.disable_open_click_delay` in `about:config`).  If you call the `click()` event from code without a user click occurring then the first step, the enabling of `window.open()` never occurs, though the call to `window.open()` will itself succeed [to stop sites detecting that you have popup blocking enabled](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=181035).

I'm not sure how other browsers implement this stuff but it would be surprising to me if it was much different.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that calling `click` via jQuery actually doesn't really trigger a click on the element, but instead calls the function listening to the click. So although you are calling `click()` you are actually just calling a function.

When the user clicks, it is a real click.

Example:

```
var handler = function () {
    alert('hi');
};

$('#example').on('click', handler);
$('#example').click(); // really just calls handler();
```

Comment: Is that also true of the native javascript .click()?

Comment: Interesting thing to note: If you, as the user, do anything that results in the click code being executed, it still does. This includes clicking on something that calls the `click` event. Or even a key press event can call it and it'll work.

Comment: It is hard to predict how the browser implements this check as there is nothing in the specification to dictate when the user should be prompted. http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-2651361

Comment: "really just calls handler()" - Well, that's not entirely true. jQuery will pass an event object to the handler function if you do the $('#example').click(); i.e. if your handler is var hadler=function(e){ /*e is an event object here*/ }

Answer (score 0):

The browser's native code handles the actual mouse click event (from the operating system) and creates the browser event object.  At that point in the browser's native code, the browser knows that this event was created by a real mouse click.

My guess would be that there is some hidden data (not accessible from javascript) attached to the event which lets the browser keep track of whether the event was initiated via a real mouse click or not though there could be other implementation mechanisms too.